# Npm test in Jenkins build takes 8 hours

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins build is still not finished after 8hrs. I have a simple React project I want to implement Continuous Integration with.

My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node'
            args '-u root'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building...'
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm install node'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing...'
                sh 'npm test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think what is happening is npm test is testing ALL the node modules. The build itself takes 44s.

Also, I have not been able to get npm install to install the node modules? So far as I understand it should install node automatically?

How can I stop it taking so long?

Comment: You haven't provided anything that can help identify what the problem is.

Comment: Could you show the jenkins job build log and your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Override docker entrypoint with command `--entrypoint \'\'`

agent will therefore look like

```
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node'
            args '-u root --entrypoint \'\''
        }
    }
```

This is a wild guess, all I can do with so little information